# I got this error when Archive the project "error: Abort trap: 6"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

App runs good in simulator and mobile but I can't take build. I updated my xcode 10.1, then archive my project but it was failed. it showing this error

> `While deserialising SIL vtable for 'OverlayManager' in module 'Instructions'` error: Abort trap: 6

- I tried clean project
- delete derived data
- reopen the project.
- removed the arm7

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/ephread/Instructions/issues/197)?

Comment: Yes I tried this => I tried clean project, delete derived data , reopen the project &
removed the arm7 but no improvement.

Comment: is your swift version >= 4.2?

Comment: No, Swift version => 4

Comment: it was fixed when updated the swift 4 to 4.2